# Extract values by their position

Tags: linux, grep

Using the histogram function of gdalinfo, I am saving the frequency of pixel values in a textfile. My objective is to extract the first and last value of the histogram and save them in a variable. Since I am new the Linux environment, I don't know how to use grep to select the numbers by their position.

```
13691313 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24599
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the first and last field with awk:

```
awk '{ print $1, $NF }' filename
```

Or, if your histogram is stored in a string, you can use a here-string:

```
awk '{ print $1, $NF }' <<< "$stringname"
```

If you'd like to assign them separately to shell variables:

```
$ var1="$(awk '{ print $1 }' filename)"
$ var2="$(awk '{ print $NF }' filename)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string does not change, ie. same amount of space you can use

```
echo "your string" | cut -d " " -f 1,256
```

And cut should show

> 13691313 24599

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^` and `$` to anchor the grep expression at the beginning or end:

```
echo "your string" | grep -oE '(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)'
```